# Finding leaves in binary tree in Ada

Tags: tree, binary-search-tree, ada

I've got BSt written in Ada and I'm trying to print leaves. Here's Tree and Node code

```
type Node;
type Tree is access Node;
type Node is record
  Item:  Integer;
  Left,Right:  Tree;
end record;
```

I can check if Tree is not null, but if I check if Tree.Left or Tree.Right is null I'm getting

```
raised CONSTRAINT_ERROR : access check failed
```

in line with e.g.

```
if (T.Left/=null) then
```

How can I check if node has no children?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because `T` istelf is `null`, and a leaf

Comment: If `T` is `null`, it isn’t anything! It’d be better to avoid making the recursive call with a null pointer, I think. Assuming you are doing this using recursion?

Comment: Ah, yes. The _parent_ of `T` would be a leaf, not `T`. Suits me right for mentally making changes to a half-written sentence...

Comment: Erm, *might* be a leaf - only if *both* *it’s* `Left` and `Right` were `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

if  T /= null then
  if T.left = null and T.right = null then
     -- leaf node!